# adding the quantity of matching objects

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

here is my code the if statement seems to never be true but I don't know what is wrong with it. I have also tried replacing the '("A" + currentRow)' with '("A:A")'

```
function addAllValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"),
      type = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues(),
      length = sheet.getRange("C2:C").getValues(),
      model = sheet.getRange("D2:D").getValues(),
      make = sheet.getRange("E2:E").getValues(),
      specs = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues(),
      add = sheet.getRange("G2:G").getValues(),
      quantity = sheet.getRange("H2:H").getValues(),
      currentRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveSelection().getRowIndex(),
      i=0,
      value=0;

    do{
      if(type == ("A" + currentRow) && length == ("B" + currentRow) && model == ("C" + currentRow) && make == ("D" + currentRow) && specs == ("E" + currentRow))
      {
        if(add == "add"){ value = value + quantity}else{ value = value - quantity}
      }
      i++;
    }while(type[i] != "")
  return value;

}
```

The purpose of this function is to look through one sheet and add up all the matching items to update the quantity of another sheet. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at just one part of the comparison...

```
if(type == ("A" + currentRow) ...
```

Here's how `type` is declared:

```
type = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues()
```

That means that `type` is a two-dimensional array of values, or an array of rows where each row is an array of cells... just one cell wide, in this case. It might be something like this:

```
[ [4],
  [34],
  [23] ]
```

The value we're comparing `type` to is `("A" + currentRow)`. The variable there is declared like this:

```
currentRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveSelection().getRowIndex()
```

... which will be a number. The expression `"A" + currentRow` will coerce that number to a string, yielding something like `A5` (assuming the cursor was currently in row 5).

The comparison is checking whether that 2-D array is equal to a simple string... and it never is.

Work through your comparison again, and make sure that you're comparing the values you really want to. For debugging a long `if` statement like that, break it into separate parts and walk through each one independently to make sure you have it right.

Comment: thank you very much this was very useful i am having one more problem though this:  value = value + quantity[i] comes out as adding a string for example 01114 when it should be 0+1+1+14=16

Comment: This is another example of that "coercion" behaviour in JavaScript. If your first operand, `value`, contained a string (even if that string represented a number), and you add a number to it, the second operand will be coerced to be a string, then the strings will be concatenated. You can coerce the first operand to be a number by _adding it to (implied) zero_, like this: `value = +value + quantity[i]`

Comment: that did not fix the problem is there another way to force it to be a integer

Comment: Try the JavaScript built-in `parseInt()`.

Comment: thank you this made it work i will post the working script now

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Mogsdad i was able to get it working. Here is the working script

```
`function addAllValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"),
      type = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues(),
      length = sheet.getRange("C2:C").getValues(),
      model = sheet.getRange("D2:D").getValues(),
      make = sheet.getRange("E2:E").getValues(),
      specs = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues(),
      add = sheet.getRange("G2:G").getValues(),
      quantity = sheet.getRange("H2:H").getValues(),
      currentRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveSelection().getRowIndex(),
      i=0,
      value=0;
 //var hi = ss.getRange("A" + currentRow).getValue()
    do{
      if(type[i] == ss.getRange("A" + currentRow).getValue() && length[i] == ss.getRange("B" + currentRow).getValue() && model[i] == ss.getRange("C" + currentRow).getValue() && make[i] == ss.getRange("D" + currentRow).getValue() && specs[i] == ss.getRange("E" + currentRow).getValue())
      {

        if(add[i] == "add"){value = parseInt(value,10) + parseInt(quantity[i],10)}else{ value = parseInt(value,10) - parseInt(quantity[i], 10)}
      }
      i++;
    }while(type[i] != "")
  return value;

}`
```